# Argument of type 'MyCustom' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean' encodeURIComponent() - typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am a typescript newbie. I have a very simple code which looks like this

```
type MyCustom = null | string | number | boolean | Date;

function encode(param: MyCustom) {
    encodeURIComponent(param);
}
```

I am geeting this complie time error

`Argument of type 'MyCustom' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | boolean'.
  Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.
    Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

How do i get rid of the compile error? Can I make any changes to the MyCustom type to fix this. The MyCustom in from a npm package that I wrote and the function encode() is wriiten by a customer. I would like not to make any changes to the customer code.

Thanks in advance